# Haskell- find element in a list

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function that takes a number `i` and a list of numbers `xs` and
returns the position of `i` in the list `xs`, counting the first position as 1. If `i` does
not occur in `xs`, then `position` returns 0.

So far I have this:

```
import Data.List
position :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
position i xs 
   | i `elem` xs = i `elemIndex` xs
   | otherwise = 0
```

But when I compile, it gives the following error:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Maybe Int’

I know that `elemIndex` returns a `Maybe Int` type and I defined my function to return `Int` but I don't know how to change it. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use fromJust(defined in Data.Maybe) to unwrap the value if you are sure that the it's always a Just.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, lists are indexed with `0…`. So `elemIndex` will return `Just 0` if `i` happens to be the first element of your list.

Since `elemIndex` returns `Maybe Int`, you could pattern match on its result instead:

```
import Data.List (elemIndex)

position :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
position i xs =
    case i `elemIndex` xs of
       Just n  -> n + 1
       Nothing -> 0
```

Answer (score 6):

I think, the solution above could be one-liner using the `maybe` function:

```
import Data.List

position :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
position i xs = maybe 0 (+1) $ i `elemIndex` xs
```

Comment: Does it not need `import Data.Maybe (maybe)` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent no. `maybe` is (re-)exported by `Prelude`.

Answer (score 1):

You could even use the zip function in the standard prelude of haskell :) 
Just zip it with [1..] and then use the list comprehension provided by it.
Check out the code here:

`positions n xs = [y | (y,z) <- zip [1..] xs, z==n]`

To find the number of occurences,  just use length from the standard prelude:

`positions n xs = length [y | (y,z) <- zip [1..] xs, z==n]`

Answer (score 0):

This works properly:

```
=>> findK k l = l !! k
```